# CSS: overflow: hidden no me funciona en etiqueta figure

Tags: html, css

Tengo en cuentas resumidas este código en HTML:

```
<section id="contenido">
    <article class="item">
        <figure class="imagen_item">
            <img src="images/img7.jpg" />
        </figure>
    </article>
</section>
```

y el estilo CSS:

```
#contenido .item .imagen_item
{
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1em;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#contenido .item .imagen_item img
{  
    max-width: 96px;
}
```

Pero no logro que se corte la iamgen cuando se desborda... me queda así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aiudaaa. Saludos.

El proyecto lo tengo en github:
https://github.com/RamsesMartinez/Puls

Comment: Según w3schools: "its position is independent of the main flow", por lo que se podría interpretar como que no se le aplican las normas, pero no sabria decirte... yo lo quitaría y usaría un border o algo así.

Comment: intenta con un width 100% aver si te funciona.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estabas muy cerca. Sólo tenías que agregarle `height` al mismo contenedor que tiene el `overflow`. También puedes agregarle `max-height` si quieres que tenga altura variable. Algo así

```css
#contenido .item .imagen_item {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 100px;
}
#contenido .item .imagen_item img {
  max-width: 96px;
}
```

```html
<section id="contenido">
  <article class="item">
    <figure class="imagen_item">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9uzO.png" />
    </figure>
  </article>
</section>
```

De esa forma le estas diciendo desde donde quieres empezar a cortar (ocultar) el contenido.

[image: El modelo de caja]

Échale un vistazo a la guía del [modelo de caja](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model) para que veas que propiedades controlan la altura de un elemento. Si no le pones dimensiones al elemento esta es controlada por las dimensiones de su contenido

Comment: Me funcionó mucho! Muchas gracias amigo.

Answer (score 2):

Debes de declarar la altura en tu contenido, o poner white-space: nowrap.

Aqui esta mi referencia.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow